# How to know if third argument is passed to script?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am working on a script that uses English words for their argument, not the traditional `--argument` or `-a`.

I have not dare to deal this with argparse, but when I do this with sys.argv like this:

```
if sys.argv[3]:
    print('yes, there is a third argument')
```

I get an `IndexError: list index out of range`. What is the possible way to tackle this? I want to know if there is third argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `len()` to check the length first or catch the `IndexError`.

```
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    # all three arguments are present
    print 'arg1', sys.argv[1], 'arg2', sys.argv[2], 'arg3', sys.argv[3]
```

or:

```
try:
   arg1, arg2, arg3 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]
except IndexError:
   # arguments are missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to check the length of `argv`:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    print('yes, there is a third argument')
```

If you have time, though, it's worth learning argparse.  It's not too scary, and it makes your code much easier to read.